# PayPal IPN for solved disputes with a different refund amount offered by the seller

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am integrating PayPal with my site and testing in sandbox.

When the buyer opens a dispute in PayPal Resolution Center to requests a refund, then we receive an IPN with `payment_status = Reversed` (the refund amount requested by the buyer is removed from the seller's account balance).

Then if the seller agrees to send the full refund, closing the case, then we receive an IPN with `payment_status = Canceled_Reversal` (the refund amount requested by the buyer is returned to the seller's account balance) and another IPN with `payment_status = Refunded` (the refund amount requested by the buyer is removed from the seller's account balance and finally returned to the buyer's account balance).

This is the IPNs' `payment_status` sequence for such case: `Reversed` > `Canceled_Reversal` > `Refunded`

However, the issue occurs when the seller offers a different refund amount to the buyer, who agrees with it, getting the offered amount back and closing the case.

This is the IPNs' `payment_status` sequence for such case: `Reversed` > `Refunded`

It seems to me that the IPN with `payment_status = Canceled_Reversal` is missing. I need it for financial purposes.

What is wrong? Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to PayPal. But do the amounts provided in the two IPNs tally to reality?

Comment: @user207421 yes